# Compare Numbers in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an ArrayList of numbers, I want to compare the list of numbers against a number stored in an variable.

For example 7 is stored in the variable, and my array consists of,

5 1 2 4

How would I compare each number in the array in order against the one next to it to see if it equals 7? then if the numbers do equal or is less than 7 move them to the back of the number list.

i.e 5 + 1 = 6 but 5 + 1 + 2 = 8 so 5 and 1 moves to the back of the list and it becomes 2 4 5 1.

At the moment I have a few if statements but they do not hold up and give me out of bounds exceptions when I run it.

Edit:
This is what I've so far which covers 1 condition of what I want it to do.

for(int z = 0; z < sum; z++)
            {

```
            System.out.println(arr);

            if(arr.get(z) == sum )
            {

                arr.add(z);
                arr.remove(z);
                tot = total2 + arr.get(z);

            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it,

```
public static boolean contains(int[] arr, int v) {
    // need a minimum of two elements to do the addition..
    if (arr == null || arr.length {
        return false;
    }
    // Loop from 0 to 1 less then the length of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        // check if the current element + the next element == value
        if (arr[i] + arr[i + 1] == v) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(contains(new int[] { 5, 1, 2, 4 }, 7)); // false
    System.out.println(contains(new int[] { 5, 2, 4 }, 7)); // true
}
```

Output is

```
false
true
```